# How to change component className received as a props

Tags: reactjs

How to change component className received as a props

`main.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react';


/**
 * 
 * @param Img <img src="..." />
 * @returns JSX.Element
 */
export default ({ img }) => (
  <div>
    {img()}  {/* <-- How to add or replace className */}
  </div>
}
```

`use.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Main from './main';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Main img={() => <img src="..." />} />
  </div>
);
```

expected results

```html
<div>
  <!-- main.jsx -->
  <div>
    <img src="..." class="test" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React from 'react';


/**
 * 
 * @param Img <img src="..." />
 * @returns JSX.Element
 */
export default ({ img }) => {
  const ModifyImg = () => React.cloneElement(img(), {
    className: 'test',
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <ModifyImg />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new names while destructuring.

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * 
 * @param Img <img src="..." />
 * @returns JSX.Element
 */
export default ({ Img: newName }) => (
  <div>
    {newName()}  {/* <-- How to add or replace className */}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I got the answer and I don't know what to do. So I edited the question to be more detailed.